# How to Install Emacs latest stable release?

Tags: spacemacs, linux

I'm trying to install spacemacs on my laptop with elementary os. With apt the latest version I get is 26.3 and I don't understand why because it seems to be far away from the most recent stable release. What would be the correct way to install the most recent stable release of emacs such that this version runs when I execute the emacs command in a terminal.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By the way, the latest stable release is not 28.1 but 28.2.

Answer (score 2):

To have the latest version of Emacs installed I recommend you to install Emacs with flatpak (you need to have  [flatpak installed](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-install-and-use-flatpak-linux/)) or with snap (snap is installed by default on ubuntu distributions).

- Do `$ flatpak install flathub org.gnu.emacs` to [install Emacs with flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnu.emacs).
- Do `$ sudo snap install emacs --classic` to [install Emacs with snap](https://snapcraft.io/emacs).

To keep Emacs updated, do

- `$ flatpak update` if you use flatpak,
- `$ sudo snap refresh` if you use snap.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary OS is an Ubuntu derivative, so you should be able to add the 3rd party [Emacs PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelleyk/+archive/ubuntu/emacs) to your system and install their build of Emacs which is on 28.1 as of 2022-05-31.  In your shell, do the following:

```bash
# First remove the stock emacs package
sudo apt remove emacs
sudo apt autoremove
# Then install the newer emacs.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs
sudo apt update
sudo apt install emacs28-nativecomp
```

I recommend installing emacs28-nativecomp instead of plain old emacs28, because it's significantly faster.  If that worked, then you can install [Spacemacs](https://www.spacemacs.org/) by doing:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs ~/.emacs.d
```